# Where in the Spring documentation is referencing beans from SpEL expressions explained?

Tags: spring, documentation, spring-el

I've looked up the documentation on SpEL, but I couldn't find an explanation for the following SpEL expression:

```
#{@someBean}
```

Or

```
#{@someBean.property}
```

I've seen it used in a few examples and in some SO answers, but I can't find where this behavior is documented. Or I overlooked it (multiple times).

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: probably here https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: The combination "#{@" doesn't occur even once in this 45k character counting document. However, now knowing what this does, I know how to reverse search the documentation. And indeed bean referral is described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references though not in combincation with a SpEL annotation (the common use case).

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the context. If you are going to use bean reference during the configuration phase and use those `#{}`  templates, then you don't need a bean reference operator: the `BeanExpressionContext` does direct `BeanFactory` access via its:

```
@Nullable
public Object getObject(String key) {
    if (this.beanFactory.containsBean(key)) {
        return this.beanFactory.getBean(key);
    }
    else if (this.scope != null) {
        return this.scope.resolveContextualObject(key);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is what Spring Framework prepares for us in its `EmbeddedValueResolver`.

If you parse expressions yourself at runtime and use something like `StandardEvaluationContext`, then you indeed need a bean reference operator (`@`) to reach your bean via `BeanFactoryAccessor`.